# Nested Parse Http Request issue

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I'm using Parse as a backend for my application and I want to resize all the users Images, I'm running a parse query on all the users and then resizing the Images.

I'm facing a problem I'm getting an error for my http request

> Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'url' of undefined

I think I should use promises but I'm not sure.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("userMigration", function(request, status) {
    // Set up to modify user data
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var Image = require("parse-image");
    var counter = 0;
    // Query for all users
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.each(function(user) {
        // Update to plan value passed in
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: user.get("Profilepic").url()
        }).then(function(response) {
            var image = new Image();
            return image.setData(response.buffer);
        }).then(function(image) {
            // make it fit in 100x100
            var width = 100,
                height = 100;
            if (image.width() > image.height()) {
                // work out scaled height
                height = image.height() * (100 / image.width());
            } else {
                // work out scaled width
                width = image.width() * (100 / image.height());
            }
            console.log("..scale to " + width + "x" + height);
            return image.scale({
                width: width,
                height: height
            });
        }).then(function(scaledImage) {
            // get the image data in a Buffer
            return scaledImage.data();
        }).then(function(buffer) {
            // save the image to a new file
            console.log("..saving file");
            var base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
            var name = "Thumbnail.png";
            var thumbnail = new Parse.File(name, {
                base64: base64
            });
            return thumbnail.save();
        }).then(function(thumbnail) {
            // attach the image file to the original object
            console.log("..attaching file");
            user.set("Profilepic_thumb", thumbnail);
            return user.save();
        });


    }).then(function() {
        // Set the job's success status
        status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    });
});
```

Full Error

> Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'url' of undefined
>       at null. (main.js:282:33)
>       at e (Parse.js:2:8941)
>       at Parse.js:2:9694
>       at g (Parse.js:2:9431)
>       at c.extend.then (Parse.js:2:9679)
>       at main.js:280:29
>       at null. (Parse.js:3:19941)
>       at e (Parse.js:2:8941)
>       at Parse.js:2:9694
>       at g (Parse.js:2:9431)

Comment: You forgot to `return` the `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` promise btw. Also sharing the error stack would be very helpful.

Comment: I added it, the Cloud http Request works fine, but when nesting it in the query results, it shows the error.

Comment: I think it's `user.get("Profilepic").url()`. maybe `user.get("Profilepic")` is undefined?

Comment: Yes that's the error

Comment: does this solve your problem? `var profilePic = user.get("Profilepic"); if (!profilePic) return; /*and then later*/ {url: profilePic.url() }`